# Difficulty in proving Estimation lemma for a contour.

Tags: complex-integration

I have already proved Estimation lemma when the complex integration is taken over a smooth curve but I find difficulty to prove it when the complex integration is taken over a piecewise smooth curve i.e. over a contour.

Please help me in proving this.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** $:$

Actually I find difficulty to prove that

$$\left|\int_{\gamma} f(z)\ dz \right| \leq \int_{\gamma} |f(z)|\ |dz|.$$

if $\gamma$ is a contour instead of a smooth curve.

> **My attempt** $:$
>
> Let $\gamma$ having parametric interval $[a,b]$ be composed of finite number of smooth curves say $\gamma = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 + \cdots + \gamma_n$ where each $\gamma_j$ is smooth in it's own parametric interval $[t_{j-1} , t_j]$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$, where $t_0 = a$ and $t_n = b$.Assuming that $f$ is continuous on $\{\gamma \}$.Let $f(\gamma (t)) \leq M$ for all $t \in [a,b]$.Then
>
> $$\left | \int_{\gamma} f(z)\ dz \right | = \left | \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} f(\gamma_k (t)) {\gamma_k}' (t)\ dt \right | \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left | \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} f(\gamma_k (t)) {\gamma_k}' (t)\ dt \right | \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} \left | f(\gamma_k (t)) \right | \left | {\gamma_k}' (t) \right |\ dt  \leq M \sum_{k=1}^{n} L(\gamma_k) = ML(\gamma).$$
>
> Which proves the required Estimation lemma.

Comment: Why can't you split $\gamma$ into it's constituent pieces $\gamma_{1}, \gamma_{2}$ etc, then apply the triangle inequality as you do in the estimation lemma?

Comment: I find an idea! Can I give it as an answer.

Comment: @Mattos please verify my attempt whether it is correct or not.